# How to append span tag in div tag using jquery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var jq = jQuery.noConflict();
    jq(document).ready(function() {
    jq('<span></span>').appendTo('.gallery-slider .nivo-caption');
    });
   });
</script>
```

in html

```
 <div class="gallery-slider">
         ...
        ....
   <div class="nivo-caption">Hello Dude</div>
    </div>
```

It is not working... Please help me!!!

Comment: What do you expect to see when you append an empty span? Remove the extra `});` from the end of your code and it will work: http://jsfiddle.net/r7j8t/

Comment: Bascially the content is appended in the div with the class nivo-caption by the plugin file. I want that the content should be kept in span tag

Comment: What content? What plugin? What if you apply the class to the span that you append before you call whatever plugin you are talking about? Or run the plugin first and then use the `.wrapAll()` method.

Comment: Like <div class="nivo-caption"><span>Hello Dude</span></div>

Answer (score 3):

Use [wrapInner()](http://api.jquery.com/wrapInner/) to wrap all children of an element

```
jq('.gallery-slider .nivo-caption').wrapInner('<span></span>');
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/25Uy2/)

Comment: +1. (Why do I always forget about `.wrapInner()` and try to do it as in my answer? This isn't the first time I've done so...)

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be mistake with parenthesis, but I think (and hope) is just a bad cut/paste.

Have you tried it this way?

```
  $.noConflict();
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // Code that uses jQuery's $ can follow here.
  });
```

As in the example [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) provided?

Hope it helps.

Comment: Notice that on the jQuery doco page you linked to it also explains that you can use the `var someVar = jQuery.noConflict();` method used by the OP. [It works](http://jsfiddle.net/r7j8t/).

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/2dJAN/53/

```
<div class="gallery-slider" style="height:100px; width:200px; background-color:red;"></div>

$('.gallery-slider').append("<span style='background-color:green;'>I am a span</spn>");
```